# UIView should catch tap event but pass on moving events

Tags: ios, uiview, touch-event

I have two views, one above another as a child.
View1--->View2 (View1 has View2 as a child)

How can I code this functionality?
1) if user TAPed on View2 - so the proper message tapped: sent to View2;
2) if user just moving finger over the View1(including View2) - events passed to View1 so it can handle touchesBegan: and so on.

So what I am trying to code is make one function "[View2 tapped:...]" if touch was short, and another function([View1 touchesBegan:..] and so on) if touch is moving.

In my case if I move finger over View2 - it never passes events to View1.

P.s. I did not rewrite hitTest or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gesture recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) handle this sort of logic quite elegantly. Have a [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on view2, and do whatever you want on view1 (e.g. a [`UIPanGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). That takes care of all of the "what gestures are recognized by what views" logic you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `UIGestureRecognizers`. One of them is `UITapGestureRecognizer` - catches taps on targeted `UIView`. It's very simple to use. Look Apple [documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)